# Security Exception: android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS

Tags: java, android, android-securityexception

Just faced this exception under my application PID in the Android Monitor, while not doing anything special. First time I'm seeing such thing, any explanation/docs? Thanks

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: 
    broadcast from android asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0;
    this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL or 
    android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to disable auto-fill, but it works only on Android Oreo. Check this link [Disabling Android O auto-fill service for an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731372/disabling-android-o-auto-fill-service-for-an-application)