# Android 8.0 Oreo crash on focusing TextInputEditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-8.0-oreo, android-textinputlayout

After updating some of our devices to android 8.0 , upon focusing on a `TextInputEditText` field inside of a `TextInputLayout`, the app crashes with this `Exception`:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
android.view.View.getBoundsOnScreen(android.graphics.Rect)' on a null object reference
at android.app.assist.AssistStructure$WindowNode.(AssistStructure.java)
at android.app.assist.AssistStructure.(AssistStructure.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRequestAssistContextExtras(ActivityThread.java:3035)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1807)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

When we go to android **Settings -> System -> Languages & input -> Advanced -> Auto-fill service -> None** , then focusing on the `TextInputEditText` `/` `TextInputLayout` no longer crashes.

**How can we prevent the crash from happening without having to disable the new 8.0 Auto-fill service on the devices?**

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62834931

Answer (score 193, accepted):

I ran into this too.  It turns out the issue was caused by setting the hint text on the `EditText` nested inside the `TextInputLayout`.

I did some digging and found this nugget in the 26.0.0 Beta 2 release notes.
[Android Support Release Notes June 2017](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)

> TextInputLayout must set hints on onProvideAutofillStructure()

That led me to try setting the hint on the `TextInputLayout` instead of the nested `EditText`.

This resolved the crashing issue for me. Example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Some Hint Text"
    android.support.design:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
    android.support.design:hintEnabled="true"
    android.support.design:layout_marginTop="16dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I posted this as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731372/disabling-android-o-auto-fill-service-for-an-application/47021399#47021399) as I mixed up bookmarks. Sorry for posting the same answer twice.

Comment: Will this work without android.support.design:hintAnimationEnabled and android.support.design:hintEnabled? I looked at TextInputLayout source, both attributes seem to be set as default when loading attributes.

Comment: @androidguy yes it should work without those attributes. Those attributes tell the TextInputLayout to allocate space in the layout for those items(or at least that is what I have observed)

Comment: @Azethoth This solution doesn't retain the behaviour. In my case, I am using it for floating label animation. When I use it this way, the hint/label doesn't appear. All I can see is a textinput

Comment: @KrishnaCA that is quite weird. I use this approach everywhere in my app and it both shows the hint in the edit text and animates it as a floating label. I'm not sure what may be causing your issue. Can you post a code sample of your xml layout in a question and link me to it? I'd be happy to try and assist.

Comment: It’s the same as posted in your answer. The device that I tested for is Huawei

Comment: @KrishnaCA I wonder if it is something to do with whatever Huawei does for their flavor of Android. Have you tested on an emulator or other device? You can also avoid this crash by setting the hint on the edit text in code.  The bug manifests when hint is set in xml.

Comment: it's not only with edittext, I had to remove hint from all nested views of TextInputLayout

Answer (score 26):

Add below mentioned attribute in your `EditText`:

`android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"`

Comment: Feature is only for API 26 is there a solution if your min API is less than 26?

Comment: @JPM No worries, it's just ignored in older API levels so won't crash or be an issue.

Comment: @JPM issue is on Oreo only, so it will get ignored for older APIs and will not crash for them.

Comment: I have it in PROD now on my app seems to be working just fine

Comment: @JPM That's great !!

Comment: This is incorrect solution. It crashes when you long press on EditText and choose Autofill from the menu. Correct (although requires code) solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46698028/1714102

Answer (score 12):

Luke Simpson almost make it right, just should use "styles.xml" instead of "themes.xml".

I created a new style file with version qualifier, aiming to v26, to make it clearer. 
Just copy and paste your `AppTheme` for the v26/styles.xml and add `editTextStyle` items the `EditTextStyle` style.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/App_EditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/App_EditTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="App_EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:importantForAutofill">noExcludeDescendants</item>
</style>
```

In this way you make this changes for **all** your EditTexts without needing to change your layout files.

Comment: Will note the min API requirement, will need to place in the v26 resource folder.

Answer (score 6):

I used the v26/themes.xml to override the EditText style autofill only for Oreo 8.0.0:

```
<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:importantForAutofill">noExcludeDescendants</item>
</style>
```

Note that I had to apply the style inline for each EditText in my layout xml for it to take effect. I tried to apply this change globally in my app theme but it didn't work for some reason.

```
// HAD TO DO THIS IN LAYOUT XML FOR EACH EDIT TEXT
<EditText
    style="@style/EditTextStyle"
    ... />


// THIS DIDN'T TAKE EFFECT IN THEMES XML (HAS BEEN ADDED TO MANIFEST)
<style name="APP_THEME" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set any value for [importantForAutofill](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#importantForAutofill) with a style or in the XML it's fix for NPE when you focus the EditText but it's not fix if your long press the EditText and you click on AutoFill. I found a Bug Report about this bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67675432), please add a star and share your observations in the bug report also.

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

@Luke Simpson is right. You can use it in themes.XML like:-

```
<item name="editTextStyle">@style/AppEditTextStyle</item>

and then put
<style name="AppEditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="android:importantForAutofill">auto</item>
 </style>
```

in V26/app_styles.xml

But, I had to put empty tag also in app_styles.xml in the default folder. Otherwise, all the properties of Edit text were getting overriding by this and my edit text was not working properly.
And when you put importantForAutoFill property for v26 and you want autofill to work in 8.1, you can simply put

```
<style name="AppEditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="android:importantForAutofill">auto</item>
    </style>
```

So, autofill property works in 8.1. It will be disabled just for 8.0 as the crash is hapenning in 8.0 and it has already been fixed in 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still wants "**hint**" in "**TextInputEditText**" make **app:hintEnabled="false"** in **TextInputLayout**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also facing this issue and finally we got the reason of crash on android 8.0 and android 8.1.

first reason(important clue): empty hint(android:hint="") in xml leads to crash in oreo device.Please remove this empty hint in editText in whole project search.

second reason(same as above explain): make sure your editText hint should be show inside TextInputLayout if you have used TextInputLayout otherwise you can use hint inside editText.

Hope this helpe you !!

Thank you