# Android - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.getBoundsOnScreen(android.graphics.Rect)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-view

I have a simple address form like this:

Java:

```
public class NewAddressActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextInputLayout mStreetLayout;
private TextInputLayout mNumberLayout;
private TextInputLayout mNeighborhoodLayout;
private TextInputLayout mCityLayout;
private TextInputLayout mStateLayout;
private TextInputLayout mCepLayout;
private TextInputLayout mPhoneLayout;
private EditText mStreetText;
private EditText mNumberText;
private EditText mComplementText;
private EditText mNeighborhoodText;
private EditText mCityText;
private EditText mStateText;
private EditText mCepText;
private EditText mPhoneText;

private Address mAddressEditing;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_address);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    mStreetLayout = findViewById(R.id.street_layout);
    mNumberLayout = findViewById(R.id.number_layout);
    mNeighborhoodLayout = findViewById(R.id.neighborhood_layout);
    mCityLayout = findViewById(R.id.city_layout);
    mStateLayout = findViewById(R.id.state_layout);
    mCepLayout = findViewById(R.id.cep_layout);
    mPhoneLayout = findViewById(R.id.phone_layout);
    mStreetText = findViewById(R.id.street_text);
    mNumberText = findViewById(R.id.number_text);
    mComplementText = findViewById(R.id.complement_text);
    mNeighborhoodText = findViewById(R.id.neighborhood_text);
    mCityText = findViewById(R.id.city_text);
    mStateText = findViewById(R.id.state_text);
    mCepText = findViewById(R.id.cep_text);
    mPhoneText = findViewById(R.id.phone_text);

    mAddressEditing = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(AppConstants.ADDRESS_EXTRA);

    if (mAddressEditing != null) {
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setTitle(R.string.edit_address);
        }
        mStreetText.setText(mAddressEditing.getStreet());
        mNumberText.setText(mAddressEditing.getNumber());
        mComplementText.setText(mAddressEditing.getComplement());
        mNeighborhoodText.setText(mAddressEditing.getNeighborhood());
        mCityText.setText(mAddressEditing.getCity());
        mStateText.setText(mAddressEditing.getState());
        mCepText.setText(mAddressEditing.getCep());
        mPhoneText.setText(mAddressEditing.getPhone());
        mStreetText.setSelection(mAddressEditing.getStreet().length());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_new_address, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_save:
            save();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private void save() {
    String street = mStreetText.getText().toString().trim();
    String number = mNumberText.getText().toString().trim();
    String complement = mComplementText.getText().toString().trim();
    String neighborhood = mNeighborhoodText.getText().toString().trim();
    String city = mCityText.getText().toString().trim();
    String state = mStateText.getText().toString().trim();
    String cep = mCepText.getText().toString().trim();
    String phone = mPhoneText.getText().toString().trim();

    boolean hasError = false;

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(street)) {
        hasError = true;
        mStreetLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
        mStreetLayout.setError(getString(R.string.fill_the_field));
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(number)) {
        hasError = true;
        mNumberLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
        mNumberLayout.setError(getString(R.string.fill_the_field));
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(neighborhood)) {
        hasError = true;
        mNeighborhoodLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
        mNeighborhoodLayout.setError(getString(R.string.fill_the_field));
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(city)) {
        hasError = true;
        mCityLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
        mCityLayout.setError(getString(R.string.fill_the_field));
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(state)) {
        hasError = true;
        mStateLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
        mStateLayout.setError(getString(R.string.fill_the_field));
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(cep)) {
        hasError = true;
        mCepLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
        mCepLayout.setError(getString(R.string.fill_the_field));
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)) {
        hasError = true;
        mPhoneLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
        mPhoneLayout.setError(getString(R.string.fill_the_field));
    }

    if (hasError) {
        return;
    }

    final Address address = new Address();
    if (mAddressEditing != null) {
        mAddressEditing.setStreet(street);
        mAddressEditing.setNumber(number);
        mAddressEditing.setComplement(complement);
        mAddressEditing.setNeighborhood(neighborhood);
        mAddressEditing.setCity(city);
        mAddressEditing.setState(state);
        mAddressEditing.setCep(cep);
        mAddressEditing.setPhone(phone);
    } else {
        address.setStreet(street);
        address.setNumber(number);
        address.setComplement(complement);
        address.setNeighborhood(neighborhood);
        address.setCity(city);
        address.setState(state);
        address.setCep(cep);
        address.setPhone(phone);
    }

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            if (mAddressEditing != null) {
                MainApplication.getInstance().getAddressDao().update(mAddressEditing);
            } else {
                MainApplication.getInstance().getAddressDao().insert(address);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            Toast.makeText(NewAddressActivity.this,
                    mAddressEditing != null ? R.string.address_edited_successfully :
                            R.string.address_created_successfully, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
    }.execute();
}
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/street_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/street_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/street"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/number_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/street_layout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/number_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/number"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/complement_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/number_layout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/complement_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/complement"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/neighborhood_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/complement_layout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/neighborhood_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/neighborhood"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/city_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/neighborhood_layout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/city_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/city"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/state_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/city_layout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/state_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/state"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/cep_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/state_layout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cep_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/cep"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/phone_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cep_layout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phone_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/phone"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="phone|textCapSentences"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

How you can see on java, `mAddressEditing` variable is received from intent, when it´s not null it means user wants to edit its address.

All of the fields are being filled as expected, however when I tap on an edit text to change its value it's crashing...

Crash:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
Process: br.com.fornaro.armariovirtual, PID: 5540
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.getBoundsOnScreen(android.graphics.Rect)' on a null object reference at android.app.assist.AssistStructure$WindowNode.<init>(AssistStructure.java:484)
at android.app.assist.AssistStructure.<init>(AssistStructure.java:1908)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRequestAssistContextExtras(ActivityThread.java:3035)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1807)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I have no idea why it's crashing.

Steps to reproduce:
1. Edit an adress from previous screen passing the Address object as parameter on intent
2. Click on an edit text to change it's value
3. Crash!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840856/android-8-0-oreo-crash-on-focusing-textinputedittext

Comment: Thanks Mike M.! I found a solution with your link! I will add a comment if somebody else have the same problem.

Comment: I'll do that... Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 8.0 Oreo crash on focusing TextInputEditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840856/android-8-0-oreo-crash-on-focusing-textinputedittext)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Adding this code on each Edit Text solved my problem:

```
android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"
```

Comment: its only a API 26 attribute

Comment: Hi Douglas, this also solved my issue, but I don't quite understand *why* this is the case. Why does this need to be set this way? EDIT: Nevermind, I found that it is a bug w/ the Android framework https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62834931

Comment: The user can still manually select AutoFill with this set by long pressing on a field and selecting the overflow, in there is autofill.  So it is possible to still experience a crash.
See this stack for a solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840856/android-8-0-oreo-crash-on-focusing-textinputedittext

Answer (score 86):

Problem is a known Android bug. From the Google issue tracker suggestions, setting the hint on the TextInputEditText seems to be causing the crash. Setting the hint only on the TextInputLayout fixes the crash.

> This issue only happens IF the hint is set on the nested EditText
>   inside the TextInputLayout.  I resolved it by setting the hint on the
>   TextInputLayout.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62834931
Comment #28

Comment: I prefer this solution instead of android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"
which is only an API 26 attribute

Comment: It Works! Thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 64):

Set the hint on the TextInputLayout instead of the nested EditText. It wont crash.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Phone Number">
                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/login_phone"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:singleLine="true" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Worked for me on OREO.