# Crash happening only in Android 8

Tags: android, android-studio

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 

at android.app.assist.AssistStructure$WindowNode.<init> (AssistStructure.java:484)

at android.app.assist.AssistStructure.<init> (AssistStructure.java:1908)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRequestAssistContextExtras (ActivityThread.java:3133)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1885)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:108)

at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:206)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6784)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:852)
```

I am getting this Stack trace from my play console. This crash is happening only in Android 8.0. Any help or suggestion on how to fix this will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code resulting this?

Comment: I can't find where this crash is happening, no activity name mentioned in the stack trace.

Comment: Are you sure this is complete stacktrace?

Comment: What do you mean are you sure? Yes i am pretty sure

Comment: A stack trace with no references to code you wrote is difficult to debug. I feel your pain ;-(

Comment: Provide more context. When is this happenen? Happening on ALL devices?

Comment: No solution, yet?

Comment: Nope :/ @ivan8m8

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar I've tried to replace `AppCompatEditText` over `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText`. So far, I cannot report if that solves the problem. At least, I know `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText` has some problems with `getHint` in its source code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. Found this (gona try it now, but maybe it is useful for you too in the meantime):

[Android 8.0 Oreo crash on focusing TextInputEditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840856/android-8-0-oreo-crash-on-focusing-textinputedittext)

Answer (score 1):

I have also facing this issue and finally we got the reason of crash on android 8.0 and android 8.1.

first reason(important clue): empty hint(android:hint="") in xml leads to crash in oreo device.Please remove this empty hint in editText in whole project search.

second reason: make sure your editText hint should be show inside TextInputLayout if you have used TextInputLayout otherwise you can use hint inside editText.

Hope this helpe you !!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So this crash seems only occurring Android OS Oreo with may be on specific device **Huawei**, to fix this issues just remove the `android:hint="some hint"` from `EditText` inside `TextInputLayout` and place inside `TextInputLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Some Hint Text">

      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
          android:id="@+id/editText"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

See the Google's **Bug Fixes** of **(June 2017)** [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive)