# Android Oreo disable autofill for EditText

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-autofill-manager

I'm trying to disable autofill for all `EditText`'s except my login screen. And no success yet. There is always "Autofill" option after `longPress` on `editText`. IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO_EXCLUDE_DESCENDANTS for `rootView` or IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO for view gives no effect at all.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: than make your Editext **`android:longClickable="false"`**

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are trying to block autofill.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Android O auto-fill service for an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731372/disabling-android-o-auto-fill-service-for-an-application)

Answer (score 13):

you can pass "no" to `importantForAutofill` e.g.

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:importantForAutofill="no" />
```

Comment: please update with <EditText/> as asked question does not relate with TextView

Answer (score 8):

maybe you have the same problem as I had
I mixed-up suggestion and auto-fill,
then I set [importantForAutofill](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill) to false and everything was fine