# Disabling auto-fill OTP on EditText Android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-edittext

I am using TextInputEditText in XML. When I run the application, on clicking the EditText, it shows this auto-fill from messages option (Image included). It happens only in modified androids like Vivo, Oppo, etc. Please suggest how to disable this suggestion.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Oreo disable autofill for EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47773409/android-oreo-disable-autofill-for-edittext), `android:importantForAutofill="no"`.