# Can Autofill in an Android WebView be disabled?

Tags: android, webview, autofill, android-autofill-manager

I would like to disable Autofill in an Android WebView in Oreo but I cannot find a way to do that.  I have tried AutofillManager.disableAutofillServices and cancel() in the app.  I created an onAutofillEvent() listener in the app and it does not get called when Autofill is used in the WebView.

Does anyone know how to this?

I found my answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731372/disabling-android-o-auto-fill-service-for-an-application).  Not sure why I didn't find it before I asked.

Comment: Have you tried calling `setImportantForAutofill(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO)`? See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/06/13/securing-apps-android-8p0-autofill.html) for more.

Comment: Just did tried it before I saw your comment.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you are saying that it did not work... that's bad. Is the content that you are loading into the `WebView` something public? I'd like to try to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: I'm sorry.  Yes, it did work.  Thanks again.

Comment: Whew! You had me scared for a bit! :-) Glad to hear that you have it working.

Comment: The solution from the blog post is not working for me. Could you provide more details about your implementation? I have tried setImportantForAutofill both in the onCreate from the Activity that contains the Webview, and the Webview itself.

Comment: I also need the solution, if you can, please help us.

Comment: I did what the referenced post described in my onCreate in the activity that contains the WebView:

        `webview = findViewById(R.id.webview);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            webview.setImportantForAutofill(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO);
        }`

Comment: Paul's code in previous comment doesn't work for me. I also tried `getWindow().getDecorView().setImportantForAutofill(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO_EXCLUDE_DESCENDANTS);` as well as `android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"` to no avail, for Android 10 and Android 8 phones.