# Android suggesting account names for Edit Text

Tags: android

I have an app to track parcels, so you can create a parcel by specifying name and track code. I guess that due to Android detecting the field is called "name", whenever the input gets focus I get a suggestion of names from the accounts google has stored on the phone.

How can I prevent this? These suggestions are useless in my case.

i tried specifying `textNoSuggestions` on my editText but it does not fix it.

Comment: What is mean by names from google account is it mean contacts

Comment: No, it puts the names I have on my gmail accounts or that i have put in forums etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the property android:importantForAutofill like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants">

    
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNameFirst"
        android:hint="fist name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNameLast"
        android:hint ="last name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtNameFirst"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been answered before on SO. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731372/disabling-android-o-auto-fill-service-for-an-application#answer-46698028) answer and try the workaround suggested.

It suggests that you should create your own custom EditText class by extending to AppCompatEditText and then you should override the `getAutofillType` method.