# How to stop dialog save password to Google on Android 14?

Tags: android, android-autofill-manager, password-manager, password-autofill

Since Android 8 to 13, when you want to disable Password Manager's saving password we only need to include this:

```
android:importantForAutofill="no"
```

But it seems something changed in Android 14 and that autofield exclusion doesn't work.

I also tried to include

```
android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"
```

on the parent's layout.

Also, I tried to remove `android:inputType="textEmailAddress"` and `android:inputType="textPassword"` in the TextInputEditText, but it also doesn't work.

This is the dialog that is shown in Android 14.

[Google Password Manager save dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfngZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/280236409#comment3) in the Google Issue Tracker, this appears to be intended behavior:

> Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior) Thanks for submitting this
> feedback.
>
> This behavior is working as intended on Android 14, as we updated the
> behavior of “autofill importance”. In Android 14+, Views where
> Views#isImportantForAutofill is no or noExcludeDescendants will
> typically trigger autofill when focused and are always included in the
> FillRequest data, and autofill providers will be able to show
> suggestions when relevant.
>
> The Android Autofill team is constantly looking for ways to improve
> the user experience. With this change, we expect users will be able to
> use autofill more often when they need it. Additional details can be
> found in the documentation.

So this is not a bug, Google just wants to "encourage" people to use this feature. Please check the answer from @Michael Winkler for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same bug also.

I used

> android:importantForAutofill="no"
> but this is no longer blocking the dialog to appear.

I tried also to use:

> android:isCredential="true"
> https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/passkeys

but there was no change. The autofill was still working.

**EDIT**
It seems like that I found a working solution:

Create your own EditText Class and do following:

```
    override fun getAutofillType(): Int {
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            AUTOFILL_TYPE_NONE
        } else {
            super.getAutofillType()
        }
    }
```

I got the solution from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46698028/7655782